# Grouped and stacked columns with shared series

Tags: highcharts

It's almost like this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

Except that I want to have John (or any other person) in both stacks. In my case, each person is not either Male or Female, they are part of both.

Here are my categories and series:

```
categories: [
    'Apples', 'Oranges',
],

series: [
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [1, 9],
        stack: 'Type A',
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [2, 10],
        stack: 'Type B',
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 11],
        stack: 'Type A',
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [4, 11],
        stack: 'Type B',
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [5, 12],
        stack: 'Type A',
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [6, 13],
        stack: 'Type B',
    },
    {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [7, 14],
        stack: 'Type A',
    },
    {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [8, 15],
        stack: 'Type B',
    },
],
```

But with this, I currently have all names (Janet, Joe, ...) duplicated in the legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer from [the highcharts forum](https://forum.highcharts.com/post137818.html#p137818):

> To remove duplicated names in the legend you can set series.linkedTo to ":previous" in the second series with the same name. Then you can change the series colors to be the same.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [1, 9],
    stack: 'Type A',
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [2, 10],
    stack: 'Type B',
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/psguhp3r/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `showInLegend: false` to prevent duplicates in legend and make sure that corresponding series have the same color:

```
 series: [{
    name: 'John',
    color: 'orange',
    data: [1, 9],
    stack: 'Type A',
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    color: 'orange',
    data: [2, 10],
    stack: 'Type B',
    showInLegend: false
  }
 ]
```

This piece of code causes that legend performs the same action (show/hide) for all series with the common name:

```
  events: {
    legendItemClick: function(event) {
      var series = this,
        chart = this.chart;

      var isVisible = series.visible;
      chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
        if (s.name === series.name) {
          if (isVisible) {
            s.hide();
          } else {
            s.show();
          }
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cgu0g7vm/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

Comment: Thank you. That almost solved my problem. Except that I then had different colors for the same group in different stacks. See my own reply for a solution I got from the highcharts forum.